# Multiple SQL queries

Tags: sql-server, powershell, select

I have a problem executing two SQL queries. I want to run the first query and use the result as input for the second query, but this is not working. As far as I figured out I get the right results if I execute only one query. If I execute both queries the first query is correct, but the second query is only a part of the first one.

Here is my code:

```bsh
function SQLSelect($SqlQuery) {
  $SQLServer = "server"
  $SQLDBName = "storage"
  $uid = "test"
  $pwd = "test"
  $connectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDBName;User ID=$uid;Password=$pwd;"

  $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
  $connection.Open()

  $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SqlQuery, $connection)

  $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
  $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
  $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

  return $dataSet
}

$SqlQuery1 = "SELECT [Date] FROM [Statistics] ORDER BY Date DESC"
$result1 = SQLSelect($SqlQuery1)

$result1.Tables

$SqlQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM [Statistics] WHERE Date = '2017-02-16'"
$result2 = SQLSelect($SqlQuery2)

$result2.Tables
```

and this is what I get:

```
Date
----
16.03.2017 00:00:00
16.02.2017 00:00:00
16.01.2017 00:00:00
16.02.2017 00:00:00
```

and this is what I get when I run the queries seperatly:

Query 1:

```
Date
----
16.03.2017 00:00:00
16.02.2017 00:00:00
16.01.2017 00:00:00
```

Query 2:

```
ID              : 1
STWnumber       : test
MailboxSize     : 1131
ItemCount       : 8395
Date            : 16.02.2017 00:00:00
MailboxDatabase : NoLimit
Server          : server
```

Comment: use like this in second query:                                           $SqlQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM [Statistics] WHERE Date ='+ $result1 + '"
$result2 = SQLSelect($SqlQuery2)

Comment: that is waht i want to do but I get the same results. That's why I manually typed in the WHERE condition.